Annotation-specified bean name 'solRepository' for bean class conflicts with JpaRepositoryBean while migrating to spring boot 3.2.x
I'm facing a classic issue in spring that states the following:
org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: 
Annotation-specified bean name 'solRepository' for bean class [...repository.solRepository] 
conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of the same name and class 
[org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean]
  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.checkCandidate(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:361) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
  at org.mybatis.spring.mapper.ClassPathMapperScanner.checkCandidate(ClassPathMapperScanner.java:345) ~[mybatis-spring-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
...

My repository is specified like this:
@Repository
public interface SolRepository extends JpaRepository<Solution, Long> {}

Injection:
@Inject SolRepository solRepository;

This is a common error where the name of beans collide. In this case the error persists even after changing the name of the interface or adding a name in the @Repository annotation and qualifiers. What could this issue be caused by? This issue comes while trying to migrate an application in spring 3.1.x to spring 3.2.x.

Can you change your log levels to debug to identify what is the other bean with the same name that is being initiated? That could help identify why it is happening.

I changed the logs to debug level and see that in the JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration: Did not match: ...found beans of type 'org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.suppport.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean' &solutionRepository...

It says that it's a name conflict, but I haven't seen any other dependency called like that. The error follows whichever name I put for my repository. I think it's more of a dependency issue or something related to JpaRepository itself.

any change you can create a minimum reproducible project for us to check?

Do you also have @EnableJpaRepositories somewhere ?

It looks like it has created solutionRepository and you have solRepository perhaps this has caused this duplication?
